# JS translation file is empty

Tags: magento2, localisation

I am using some translation packages from Packagist (`magento2translations/*`) and I have some translation files in my theme at `app/design/frontend/Mytheme/mytheme/i18n`. On the PHP side, they all work flawlessly. But in client-side code, the translations aren't working at all.

I tracked the problem down to the generated `js-translation.json` files. They are all empty (i.e. the only contain an empty array "`[]`").

I found some people having the same problem here and on GitHub and some (very different) solutions, but none of them have worked for me. Every time I run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy <locale>`, the deployed JSON file is still empty.

**Edit:** the `js-translation.json` is only populated in languages that I have language packages installed for, but not for languages I translated in `app/design/frontend/Omv/omv/i18n`.

Also, the translations from `app/design/frontend/Omv/omv/i18n` aren't present in `js-translation.json` - not even for languages I have a language pack for. Is this intended or a bug?

**Edit 2:** The `js-translation.json` files are *not* empty in my local development environment. I have no idea why.

Comment: Check the permission again.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh You mean before running the static content deploy command? I'm pretty sure they are set correctly, but just to be sure: can you point me to the specific steps in the Magento 2 docs that I should follow? (I am running Apache on Ubuntu - so I have a user `magento` that's in the `www-data` group.)

Comment: @RudolphGottesheim, Have you got it solved? I have same issue here!

Comment: @Zinat Nope, sorry.